# How to Skip empty columns while merging two or more columns in gridview yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

First of all, I have a view like this.

**VIEW:**

```
'label' => 'xxx',
'encodeLabel' => False,
'value' => function($q) use ($aaa, $bbb){
           $c = isset($bbb[$q->something->classId]) ? $bbb[$q->something->classId] : "";
           $d = isset($aaa[$q->something->familyId]) ? $aaa[$q->something->familyId] : "";
           return  $c . "." . $d . "." . $q->something->someName . "." . $q->something->someName;
},
'attribute' => 'xxx',
'filter' => $yyy,
```

**What I am trying to do is,**

I take four columns and merge them in to single column.
 The result looks like this: `x.y.z.a` 
 When some column is empty it looks like: `x..z.a`

**What I need:**
When Displaying the merged values, if some column has a empty value instead of the output like this: `x..z.a`
I want to avoid the space when they are empty, like this: `x.z.a`

**Expected Result:**

`x.z.a` instead of `x..z.a`

How can I change or update my code to receive the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `implode()`: http://php.net/implode, optionally combined with some filtering.

```
function($q) use ($aaa, $bbb){
    return implode('.', array_filter([
        $bbb[$q->something->classId] ?? null,
        $aaa[$q->something->classId] ?? null,
        $q->something->someName,
        $q->something->someName

    ]);
}
```

This is not Yii2 or gridview specific.

Note the `null coalesce` operator, the way I used it here is equivalent to `isset($a) ? $a : $b`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#merge()-detail) along with the `implode()` and you can do it in one line.

### ABOUT [`\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-arrayhelper.html)

**Merges two or more arrays into one recursively.**

If each array has an element with the same string key value, the latter will overwrite the former (different from array_merge_recursive). Recursive merging will be conducted if both arrays have an element of array type and are having the same key. For integer-keyed elements, the elements from the latter array will be appended to the former array. You can use [`yii\helpers\UnsetArrayValue`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-unsetarrayvalue.html) object to unset value from previous array or [`yii\helpers\ReplaceArrayValue`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-replacearrayvalue.html) to force replace former value instead of recursive merging.

Let's say I have the following arrays, with `$b` being an empty array and i want to merge them all.

```
$a = ['a'];
$b = [];
$c = ['c'];
$d = ['d'];

echo implode('.',\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge($a, $b, $c, $d));
```

The Above code will output `a.c.d`

Apart from all the above, you can use `ArrayHelper::getColumn()` to get all the values listed inside the column too if you want to use it to extract the values of a single column from an array. Means the arrays used above `$a,$b,$c and $d` can be extracted from the arrays by using `ArrayHelper::getColumn()`.

```
$array = [
    ['id' => '123', 'data' => 'abc'],
    ['id' => '345', 'data' => 'def'],
];
$result = ArrayHelper::getColumn($array, 'id');
// the result is: ['123', '345']
```

Even your default `frontend/web/index.php` file has these lines to merge  the config array from files.

```
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);
```

Comment: Let's say I have the following arrays, with $b being an empty array and i want to merge them all.

$a = ['a'];
$b = [];
$c = ['c'];
$d = ['d'];

echo implode('.',\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge($a, $b, $c, $d));

The Above code will output a.c.d


Tried using this but got an error saying base exception with it cannot contain more than two elements.

Comment: @5.1tat are you sure you have the `Yii2` latest version as it simply can't be.  The document says that it can contain **2 or more** arrays and by the way, i ran your code and it shows `a.c.d` without errors, what is the exact error message you are getting?